Client component crash in Server component, is there another way?
Inside the src/app/layout.js I have this:
import * as React from 'react';
import '@/styles/global.css';
import { config } from '@/config';
import { TonConnectUIProvider } from '@tonconnect/ui-react';

export const viewport = {
  width: 'device-width',
  initialScale: 1,
  themeColor: config.site.themeColor,
};

export default async function Layout({ children }) {

  return (
    <html lang="en">
      <body>
        <TonConnectUIProvider manifestUrl={process.env.MANIFEST_URL}>
          {children}
        </TonConnectUIProvider>
      </body>
    </html>
  );
};

And I get this error:
Error: (0 , react__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0__.createContext) is not a function

Which probably suggests that TonConnectUIProvider is a client component and use useEffect or useState somewhere.
Is there a way around it?

You need to wrap it with your own client component(using "use client"). https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/rendering/composition-patterns#using-context-providers

Also you don't need the react import at the top of the file.
